# I want to Dynamically access SQLite result set?

Tags: blackberry-webworks

I want to dynamically access SQLite result set. Since webworks/javascript doesnt support "PRAGMA table_info(table_name); I am saving all newly created tables information in a single two column table called schema. schema has two columns, table_name and column_name.

So I created a function to access table data dynamically. I use the item=results.rows.item(i) and than access row data with item.column.

column is a variable that is assigned the value from schema, representing the column_name. When I alert(column) I get the correct column_name, but when I used item.column my results are "undefined".

any advice on how to resolve this matter.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, column is a variable that holds the value of a column name, and you want to access that column from the results item. If that's the case, then this might help:

```
//Assuming "var column" has already been defined,
//and given the value of the column name to be accessed in the results item.//
var item = results.rows.item(i);
var columnValue = item[column];
```

I struggled with this too, and this is what I found/use. You put in brackets the variable containing the column name, and that's how you access it.

EDIT: This is obviously Javascript stuff, and what I used for accessing SQLite in PhoneGap. Hopefully it helps.